# Remove Index.php in url Like " laravel-project/public/login "not " laravel-project/public/index.php/login "

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I Get Problem With my laravel project

I want to remove index.php in url

like

> http://localhost/react/Lara-react/public/admin/home

And  i get 404 not found if use this

but if i use

> http://localhost/react/Lara-react/public/index.php/admin/home

it's works and

> http://localhost:8000/admin/home

^ works to

my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#pretty-urls

but not working ...

Someone help

Comment: Did you enable apache rewirte?

Comment: yes, rewirte apache is enable

Comment: Can you add your apache virtual host config?

Answer (score 1):

http://localhost/react/Lara-react/public/admin/home

Does not work as the url does not search for index.php as your root path is http://localhost.
When you fire command php artisan serve command, the root of the app becomes
http://localhost/react/Lara-react/index.php hence all the routes are appended to root creating
http://localhost/react/Lara-react/public/index.php/admin/home which make the app work

On production you too define the root path of the  project as /var/www/html/react/Lara-react/index.php.

So for development using php artisan serve command is helpful as it creates an simulated environment as production

Answer (score 1):

1). Run common  "gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf"

```
    Alias /project_name /var/www/html/project_name/public/

   <Directory /var/www/html/project_name/public>
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
  </Directory>
```

2). Add base url in 'project_name/public/.htaccess'

```
RewriteBase /project_name
```

3). finally run  "service apache2 reastart"